# Generate label cards from an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I work with list of archaeological finds in Excel spread sheets provided by volunteer archaeologists, which contain various information on the site, geographic coordinates, the type of find, date of find etc. An example of one such spread sheet would look like this:

[image]

These spread sheets are either created manually or automatically from GIS and can have 1 to several hundred lines, but always have the same structure.

To archive the finds properly each entry gets an individual label card printed out of another excel sheet using a template with 2x5 cars on one A4 page looking like this:

[image]

So far the information from the tables are copied manually to the template sheet for the cards which is obviously extremely time consuming and there has to be a better way of doing it.

I could very likely build a template for this in QGIS or Access, but neither software is suited for the use of the volunteers, who should be able to generate the cards themselves. I assume there is a way of filling the cards template from the list using some sort of VBA programming, but since I have never worked with VBA before I wanted to make sure this is possible before speding days working into it before finding out it was a waste of time. I have found various examples of simple VBA-Print-Makros but non with so many variables.

Would it be possible to fill the cards aumatically using VBA? If not, is there another Microsoft-Office-Based alternative?

Comment: Why not use the correct way for something like this? This is the perfect use for Mail Merge in Microsoft Word! You create the template in Word and then use Mail Merge to fill in the data from the Excel Sheet

Comment: If you absolutely need to do this in Excel and nothing else, you can type in the inventory number and use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH to fill the rest of the cards

Comment: @Ysroel Tech: Thanks for the input, I did not know that option. From what I found on Google during the last minutes, that should solve my problem. Could you put a basic example in the form of an answer, so the question can be solved.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: I should have clarified, that it does not have to be Excel-Only but any Microsoft-Office-Solution would have done, since this is what most people I work with use. I have edited the original question slightly to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to generate cards using data from an Excel sheet is to do it in ***Microsoft Word*** using the **Mail Merge** feature, which is designed exactly for this.

I can't walk through the whole Mail Merge process here quickly... just take any guide online for Mail Merge and it's pretty simple. It would be something like described in [***Create labels with a mail merge***](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-labels-with-a-mail-merge-in-word-4aa597cc-5a81-43fd-b829-9f50d54f5ef7#:%7E:text=Create%20your%20address%20labels,Click%20Next%3A%20Select%20recipients.):

> 1. In Word, click **Mailings** > **Start Mail Merge** > **Step-by-Step Mail Merge Wizard** to start the mail merge wizard.
> 2. Choose **Labels**, and then click **Next: Starting document**.
> 3. Choose **Label options**, select your label vendor and product number, and then click **OK**.
> 4. Click **Next: Select recipients**.
> 5. Click **Browse**, select your Excel mailing list, and then click **Open**.
> 6. Make sure the **First row of data contains column headers** box is selected and click **OK**.
> 7. Check your list. Drag the bottom right corner to make the dialog box bigger. Then click OK.
> 8. Click **Next: Arrange your labels**.
> 9. To add the address block, click **Address block** and click **OK**.
> 10. Click **Update all labels**.
> 11. Click **Next: Preview your labels**.
> 12. If the text doesn't fit, press Ctrl + A to select all, right-click and select **Paragraph**, select the **Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style** box, and click **OK**.
> 13. Click **Next: Complete the merge**.
>     14 .Click **Print**, click **OK**, and click **OK** again.

If you encounter any specific difficulties with your specific data or layout, try researching it online and if you can't find a solution you can ask it as a new question.